# MATLAB: Differentiate between children of an axes?

Tags: matlab, plot, brush

I have a function that collects brushed data (in the form of an ActionPostCallback). The function behaves as expected: when I highlight an area of a given axes, it stores the xmin and xmax of the highlighted data. However, sometimes I will plot a red rectangle around a chunk of data on the axes to draw attention to that data. If I leave that rectangle plotted on the axes, and then try to brush other data *on that same axis*, I get a callback error.

***EDIT2*** After further research, I 've found the trouble-line of code. The line in `function annotateSelectedRegion`:

```
selectedData = currentSelection.Children
```

Will cause the code to crash the moment there is more than one child, in this case the plotted rectangle and plotted line. Is there a way to differentiate between the rectangle and plotted line? Or is my best course of action just to delete the rectangle before I execute the function.

> Warning: An error occurred during the mode callback.
>
> In matlab.uitools.internal.uimode/fireActionPostCallback (line 16)
>
> In datamanager/brushup (line 117)
>
> In %522823425>@(es,ed)datamanager.brushup(es,ed)
>
> In hgfeval (line 62)
>
> In matlab.uitools.internal.uimode/modeWindowButtonUpFcn (line 55)
>
> In
>   matlab.uitools.internal.uimode/modeControl>localModeWindowButtonUpFcn
>   (line 161)

Code and screen shots attached. [image]

The thick rectangle is the plotted rectangle, and the thin rectangle is the brushing tool. This is a screen shot of a scenario that *does* produce an error.

Rectangle Plot Code

```
 function displayPrevAnnotation(obj, selectedAxes, rangeStart, rangeEnd)


        if strcmp(selectedAxes, 'Raw')
            axes(obj.rawDataDisplayAxes); 
            boxWidth = rangeEnd - rangeStart; 
            yLimits = obj.rawDataDisplayAxes.YLim;
            boxHeight = yLimits(2) - yLimits(1); 
            obj.focusBox = rectangle('Position', [rangeStart, yLimits(1), boxWidth, boxHeight]); hold off; 


        elseif strcmp(selectedAxes, 'PSD') 
            axes(obj.psdDataDisplayAxes); 
            boxWidth = rangeEnd - rangeStart; 
            yLimits = obj.psdDataDisplayAxes.YLim;
            boxHeight = yLimits(2) - yLimits(1); 
            obj.focusBox = rectangle('Position', [rangeStart, yLimits(1), boxWidth, boxHeight]); hold off; 

        end 

        obj.focusBox.LineWidth = 3;
        obj.focusBox.EdgeColor = 'red'; 

    end
```

Brushed Data Collection Function

```
function annotateSelectedRegion(obj, ~, eventdata)

    currentSelection = eventdata.Axes; 

    selectedData = currentSelection.Children; 

    if isempty(selectedData) || ~any(selectedData.BrushData(:))
        % Do nothing 
        disp('please select data or load data');

    elseif ~isempty(selectedData.BrushData)           
        brushedIdx = logical(selectedData.BrushData);
        brushedXData = selectedData.XData(brushedIdx);
        brushedYData = selectedData.YData(brushedIdx);

        obj.t1 = brushedXData(1); 
        obj.t2 = brushedXData(end); 

        fillRecPairInfo(obj); 
        fillAnnotIDInfo(obj); 
        fillUniqueIDInfo(obj); 
        fillAnnotRangeInfo(obj, currentSelection);

        annotationPopUp;

    end

end
```

Comment: "I get a callback error" – it might be helpful to see that error message in full.

Comment: @horchler pretty useless error message, but I put it in.

Comment: It might be more of a workaround rather then fixing/understanding what is actually going on, but have you tried adjusting the [`PickableParts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_pickableparts) or [`HitTest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_hittest) properties of your rectangle? You might also print out the `src` and `eventdata` inputs to your callback to see what objects are being passed to it.

Comment: @horchler So I took your advice and printed out what is being passed along and realized my mistake, or rather problem. In the line, "selectedData = currentSelection.Children;", the code will crash the moment there is more than one child (in this case the plotted line and the box). I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***NOTE:*** This solution is most applicable to my situation, I'm not sure how useful it will be to others. But anyway, here is my solution. As I stated in my question, I realized that the function "`annotateSelectedRegion`" was getting confused because of the two children present (the rectangle and the plotted line). In the function "`displayPrevAnnotation`", I simply set the "`HandleVisibility`" property of the rectangle to "`off`". By doing this, the rectangle is no longer visible to the parent, in this case, the axes and therefore the only child it sees is the plotted line.